# Why am I getting an Index out of range error on Double value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI app and I have a block of code that works perfectly when navigating from `View A` (MenuView) to `View B` (CartView). However, when navigating from `View C` to `View B`, I get a `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`.

I understand 100% how Index out of range works, my issue is that I am not working with a list but with a `Double`.

Also, I have checked in the debugger that there is actually a value when stepping through this code so the issue cannot be that the object or value is `nil`.

I do not understand how I am getting an `Index out of range` error on a `Double` value?

The specific value failing is `basePrice`.

`CartItemView.swift`

```swift
@Binding var cartItem: CartItem
@State var quantity = 1
@Binding var deleteIndex: Int
var cartItemIndex: Int
    
@State var total = 0.00
    
func updateTotal() {
    total = 0.00
    var item = cartItem
    var itemSubTotal = cartItem.basePrice
        
    for choice in cartItem.choices {
        itemSubTotal += choice.price
    }
        
    itemSubTotal = itemSubTotal * Double(cartItem.quantity)
        
    total += itemSubTotal
}
```

`Item failing`

```
▿ CartItem
  ▿ id : F9E1F7AA-8FA0-47ED-8F90-0DF865C4AD4B
    - uuid : "F9E1F7AA-8FA0-47ED-8F90-0DF865C4AD4B"
  - name : "Bacon & Avo Pizza"
  - description : ""
  - basePrice : 80.0
  - quantity : 1
  - choices : 0 elements
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This really needs an MRE to debug it.